# Recursive function with alphabetical order

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

I want to define a **recursive** function that passes a `str` and returns a `bool` telling whether or not the characters in the parameter are in alphabetical order.

Like if I defined said `sortfunc('abcdefg')` it would return `True`; and `sortfunc('banana')` would return `False`.

How would I approach this? This is what I have so far... but I'm sort of stuck. I understand the concept of recursion but I don't know how to implement it.

```
def sortfunc(s):
    if s == '':
        return False
    else:
        return True if s[0] < s[1:] else False
```

Comment: Why recursive function? Because its a Homework?

Comment: Yeap, I'm currently a student new to the language. I would like some help!

Comment: Sorry but you need to show what you've tried and what specific problem you've run into before we just do your homework for you.

Comment: @user2559679 Please add a homework tag to the question. Also, please show some effort and tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @msvalkon, [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) :)

Comment: Just tried tagging with homework tag. But I re-edited it with what I have so far.

Comment: @user2559679 since `sortfunc()` returns a bool, you shouldn't compare two booleans with `<`.

Comment: Haha, I tried seeing if I could call the function again... I didn't catch that. But this is what I had so far. I edited it again.

Comment: @Christian oh well live and learn I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible method:

```
def is_sorted(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return True               # Base case
    elif s[0] <= s[1]:
        return is_sorted(s[1:])   # Recursive case
    else:
        return False              # Base case
```

---

Explanation:

So, whenever, we want to write a recursive function, we always need to think about the following:

1. **How can I break the problem down into smaller steps?**
2. **What is the base case? (when I can stop the recursion?)**
3. **What is the recursive case? (when do I need to keep going?)**

To me, the first step is always the trickiest one -- breaking the problem down. Usually, once we figure out this step, the rest falls into place.

There are usually many different ways to break a problem down, and to a certain extent, which one you pick is a bit arbitrary. In this case, I chose to break the problem down by repeatedly comparing the first two characters in the string.

If the two characters are in order, then I repeat the process, except I remove the first character. If I have only one character left in my string, or if the first two characters are out of order, I know that I can stop and return `True` or `False` respectively.

For example, if we visualize calling `is_sorted('abcd')`, it would look something like this:

```
call is_sorted('abcd')
    'a' is less then 'b'
    call is_sorted('bcd')
        'b' is less then 'c'
        call is_sorted('cd')
            'c' is less then 'd'
            call is_sorted('d')
                only one character left, return True
            return True
        return True
    return True
```

In contrast, if we tried calling `is_sorted('azbc')`, it would look something like this:

```
call is_sorted('azbc')
    'a' is less then 'z'
    call is_sorted('zbc')
        'z' is NOT less than 'b', return False
    return False
```

So then, here are the answers to the three steps:

1. **How can I break the problem down into smaller steps?**
   Keep comparing the first two characters
2. **What is the base case? (when I can stop the recursion?)**
   Either when the two characters are out of order, or if I have only one character left
3. **What is the recursive case? (when do I need to keep going?)**
   If I have two or more characters left in my string.

Notice that the recursive case always requires a "leap of faith" -- you have to trust that calling the `is_sorted` method will accurately tell you if the rest of the string (besides the first two characters) is correctly sorted or not. It's a bit of an odd feeling -- it feels like we never explicitly told the code how to determine if the string is coded or not, or passed in any information, but it does so anyways!

However, that's part of the beauty of recursion: so long as we correctly define the base case(s) and recursive case(s), it'll magically work.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<=`?

Answer (score 1):

In your attempt you are missing the recursion part. Please check the following implementation.

```
def sortfunc(current_string, previous_character = ""):
    if current_string == "":
        return True         # Base condition
    if previous_character and previous_character > current_string[0]:
        return False        # Failure case
    return sortfunc(current_string[1:], current_string[0])  # Recursion
```

If you want to know how to do this without recursion,

```
def sortfunc(current_string):
    return "".join(sorted(current_string)) == current_string
```

**Sample runs:**

```
print sortfunc('abcdefg')   # True
print sortfunc('banana')    # False
```

Comment: It would have been easy for me to do with iteration with "".join(sorted()) but it turns out I have to do it with recursion. I can only pass one parameter as well.

Comment: @user2559679 Check the first example in the answer, that does recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Without less programming logic!

-> Split the string to an array and send this array to function

-> **we can easily compare values by converting them to respective ascii values**

```
sortfunc(str) {

for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){

if ( (int) str[i] >(int) str[i+1] ) {
result = true
}
else
result = false;

return result;
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP is learning python, so in that way the problem was python specific.